# Mercurial on IIS7 error when trying to clone repository

Tags: iis-7, mercurial, hyper-v

I have set Mercurial 1.51 up on a Hyper-V server running Windows 2008R2 and am trying to use IIS7 to serve the repositories.  I followed these [instructions](http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/mercurial-on-iis7/) which I had previously used when evaluating mercurial with success.  All was going well I could see the repositories from with a browser but when I tried to clone the repository from the server I receive the following error:

requesting all changes

abort: HTTP Error 502: Bad Gateway

I am not sure if this is an issue with IIS or Hyper-V or Mercurial?  Any suggestion much appreciated

Comment: Maybe it sounds silly, but have you the same proxy settings for your browser and mercurial?

Comment: Perfectly valid question, but not using a proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that tutorial did not instruct you to add the python IIS Handler Mapping. Take a look at this tutorial, specifically #3 under the IIS 7 section.  That may help.

[Vampire Basic: Running Mercurial on Windows](http://web.archive.org/web/20090916181255/http://vampirebasic.blogspot.com/2009/06/running-mercurial-on-windows.html) (web.archive.org mirror).

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error, in my case the workaround was to check the `use uncompressed transfer` option in the clone dialog.