# Mercurial & Windows Server 2003

Tags: iis, mercurial

I just set up Mercurial on our main webserver, hosting repositories via hgwebdir.cgi. The problem I'm having now is when I run hg push from my local machine to the server's repository, it takes an absolutely ridiculous amount of time to push a very small directory, with only a single changeset. Is it possible that I've set something up wrong? I keep getting HTTP Error 502: Bad Gateway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks a bit like [issue 2716](http://code.google.com/p/support/issues/detail?id=2716) which suggests:

Here's a workaround for the problem you are having, basically instead of doing one huge push, you
break it down into many smaller pushes:

1. Find out the number of revisions of your repository.
2. Copy and paste the following script, (in bash, use your favorite scripting language if you don't like bash):

   ```bash
   #!/bin/bash

   for rev in {1..NUM_OF_REVS}
   do
     hg push -r $rev REPO_URL
   done
   ```
3. Wait for that to run.
4. If some of the pushes fail, don't worry, the following push will catch things up.

---

That being said, issues on [Windows IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692393/mercurial-on-iis7-error-when-trying-to-clone-repository) has been reported as well.

This "[blog post comment](http://vampirebasic.blogspot.com/2009/06/running-mercurial-on-windows.html)" also details:

> - I got the same error "Bad Gateway" and solved it. Think it's about:
>
>   1. Install Mercurial 1.2.1 on the server. The version that comes with TortoiseHg is not sufficient, it will not drive the CGI application.
> - I get a "Bad Gateway" exception when trying to run `hgwebdir.cgi` from a web application which exists on a different drive to my main system drive.
> - If you're using Mercurial 1.5 make sure you are using Python version 2.6.4 to run the cgi scripts in IIS.

Comment: Thanks, I saw these when I was digging around for a solution, but my repository is very small (maybe 5mb total, 4mb of that being the .hg directory), with only 5 revisions (I'm just testing this so far). I'm using Mercurial 1.5.1 and Python 2.6.5, since those are what the latest version of each are.

Comment: @tjsimmons: interesting. Then it is a server configuration issue, for which I have no immediate element to add.

Comment: I'm thinking it's probably a server problem that I have no idea where to go about fixing. I imagine it's a combination of slow down/up speeds here (a single T1 line feeding quite a few workstations), and probably a poor setup on my behalf.

Comment: @tjsimmons: and Jeff has still yet to respond to your tweet... ;)

Comment: Haha, I figured since I heard of Mercurial from them, and I'm FAIRLY certain they run all this on IIS, they might have an idea.

Comment: Also: looking on the server, I first got a message about a failed transaction and to use hg recover, then I'm told the repo has an unknown parent. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Last wall of text: Removed the repo on the server, cloned it from my machine, push works just fine now. How did this happen? The last thing I need is for the entire website (or at least the repo) to get corrupted.