# hgweb.cgi throws a 502 (bad gateway) when pushing

Tags: mercurial, hgweb

I've configured hgweb.cgi behind iis7 on windows server 2008.  I can pull the repository just fine.  However whenever I push I get a 502 bad gateway.  I've found a [posting](http://mercurial.808500.n3.nabble.com/Mercurial-server-using-IIS7-and-CGI-Bad-Gateway-error-if-cloning-to-a-specific-revision-td1168873.html) which seems to indicate this is a problem with the mercurial config on the server.  mercurial doesnt seem to be picking up an http proxy (fiddler) from my local machine even if its configured.

Questions are:

1. how do I 'fix' the 502 problem?
2. failing that how do I make mercurial use the proxy so I can figure out whats going     wrong?
3. how do I adjust the verbosity setting for mercurial 'properly' given that this is running under a webserver?

Comment: You mjight be able to find some help by looking at the error logs.

Comment: To turn off 'verbosity', find where you have 'verbose=true' in your hgrc files.. and delete it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2700623/1077279).

I was having the same issues with pushing a repository, but it went away after I had installed a later version of Mercurial (2.0.1).  I used the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4367589/1077279), (paying attention to the comment to that post by Ethan J Brown).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is super old, but I ran across this today, and the issue was my VM where IIS was running was out of disk space! Thought I'd throw this answer out there as another possible solution.

I run a VM on my synology home nas and it's super small, only used to handle remote mercurial requests. Not really sure why it ran out of space, perhaps an update filled it up.