# hgweb.cgi throws a 502 (bad gateway) when pushing

Tags: iis-7, mercurial, hgweb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [hgweb.cgi throws a 502 (bad gateway) when pushing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973331/hgweb-cgi-throws-a-502-bad-gateway-when-pushing)

This post is a duplicate of 4973331